# Using R, how to duplicate the contents of a data frame based on the rows of another?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, analytics, tidyverse

I have 2 data frames. In df A, I have an ID number. In df B I have 52 rows, which are dates.

For each ID numebr in df A, I would like to create a new record which has that ID number for each date.

So for example, ID 001 would only appear once in df A, however it will now appear 52 times, once for each date in df B.

How do I do this?

I have created a df which contains the user IDs and I have also created a second df which has the dates. I can't join them as there's no field to join on. I through I'd need to loop through df A but don't know how.

This is how I created the date df (df B)

```
Dates <- data.frame(WCSTART = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = "weeks", length.out = 52), 
                    WCEND = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = "weeks", length.out = 52) + 6)
```

The User ID df (df A) is a static list from an excel file I've pulled in using readxl.

as I have 8074 user ID's and 52 dates. I would expect to create a new df that contained 419,848 rows.

Comment: Try `tidyr::crossing(dfA,dfB)`

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use merge() to do a merge (aka, a join), without specifying any joining variables, and everything will be duplicated as you wanted.

```
> DfA <- data.frame(id=c("001","002","003"))
> DfA
   id
1 001
2 002
3 003

> DfB <- data.frame(dates=c("2018-01-01","2018-01-02","2018-01-03"))
> DfB
       dates
1 2018-01-01
2 2018-01-02
3 2018-01-03

> output <- merge(DfA,DfB)
> output
   id      dates
1 001 2018-01-01
2 002 2018-01-01
3 003 2018-01-01
4 001 2018-01-02
5 002 2018-01-02
6 003 2018-01-02
7 001 2018-01-03
8 002 2018-01-03
9 003 2018-01-03
```

Comment: Sadly this did not work. It didn't duplicate the ID's and only returned the date for some of the records

Comment: If it didn't work for you, then you might have loaded a package that overwrote the default merge function with it's own merge function that has special properties like preventing duplicates.